# how to make second request if .catch on promise is executed?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

how can I make a second request if .catch on promise is executed , in order to get the data successfully

because if .catch is executed I did not received the data. and I have to refresh the page again to get the data.

```
fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
.then(result => result.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want to retry in the catch? You will need to call the function that makes the request again. This is called recursion. Ie:

```js
function makeRequest() {
  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return makeRequest(); // Calls itself recursively
    });
}
```

However this introduces the possibility of an infinite loop, so you need some way to break out, maybe like this:

```js
function makeRequest(attempt=0) {
  const maxRetries = 3;
  if (attempt > maxRetries) {
    throw new Error(`Could not fetch user after ${attempt} attempts`);
  }

  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      // Call self and increment the attempt number.
      // Very important to ensure that the break condition
      // can be met or we can end up calling the function
      // forever with no way to escape. This is called an
      // infinite loop.
      return makeRequest(attempt + 1);
    });
}
```

You can also make the logic more complex for retries, like introduce a timeout before the next request if `attempt` is gt 0, add exponential backoff etc.

Always remember to be careful of infinite loops when using recursive functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `fetch` and `.json()` calls into a function, then call that function once (immediately), and call it again inside the `.catch` if needed:

```
const getData = () => fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
  .then(result => result.json())

getData()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return getData();
  });
  .catch((error2) => {
    // Could not get response after 2 attempts
    console.log(error2);
  });
```

Comment: The implementation will only make two requests at most. The recursive call is not in a loop.